# What's the maximum amount of luggage that can be carried on Qatar Airways?

Tags: luggage, check-in, qatar-airways

I would be flying in Qatar Airways from Doha to Bangalore (India) and my check-in baggage allowance is 40 Kgs. Can I carry 3 bags within the limit of 40 kgs? Is there any limitation on the numbers of bags to be carried. Please help.

Comment: This is anecdotal, so I don't want to submit an "answer," but I've checked three bags under 40kg with no problem:  London-Doha-Abu Dhabi.  Best thing to do is simply contact them ahead of time to find out, or wrap two of your bags together in that ridiculous cellophane tape for 10 rial ($3 USD).

Comment: What does your e-ticket say on the matter? Checking the information you were given when you booked is likely to be quicker, easier and simpler than asking random strangers on the internet...

Comment: Wher did you get the 40kg figure from? [The Qatar website says 32kg is the maximum weight per piece.](http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/excess-baggage-rates.page)

Comment: @JoErNanO http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/baggage.page

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok thanks. Excess baggage is still 32kg maximum per piece though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The [baggage rules](http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/baggage.page) page mentions that:

> A single piece of checked baggage must not weigh more than 32kg (70lb). Any bags weighing more than 32kg (70lb) must be broken down such that each piece weighs less than 32kg (70lb).

No other restrictions are mentioned for flights to India, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check-in as many bags as you want, as long as each individual piece is less than 32 KG.

The amount you pay extra will depend on what your free allowance is based on your current reservation.

This restriction is for most airlines, including Qatar Airways and Emirates.